# JSON API response into pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert API response into panadas DF and I'm missing an idea how to get headers of the response data as a column in that DF. Below is a structure of JSON response:

```
{"success":true,
    "data":
        {"compound":
            {"baseApy":"2.44",
            "crvApy":0.9648380892351365,
            "crvBoost":1,
            "additionalRewards":[],
            "crvPrice":2.82},
        "usdt":{"baseApy":"2.00",
            "crvApy":0.009553759755528213,
            "crvBoost":1,
            "additionalRewards":[],
            "crvPrice":2.82},
        "iearn":{"baseApy":"1.16",
            "crvApy":0.5254970438646115,
            "crvBoost":1,
            "additionalRewards":[],
            "crvPrice":2.82}
```

With the following code I am getting all values from the "data" part of dictionary created in the `response`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
response = requests.get('https://api.curve.fi/api/getApys')
apy_data = response.json()
df = pd.json_normalize(apy_data['data'].values())
```

So that the df results in a table with 5 columns `"baseApy", "crvApy", "crvBoost", "additionalRewards", "crvPrice"`. What is missing from this table is a column with keys, that is `"compound", "usdt", "iearn"`

I thought that I can construct additional df with 1 column that would contain all these keys by running

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(apy_data['data'].keys())
```

But that gives me as an output indexes numbers, not the names. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added another possible solution, see if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the extra column after

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://api.curve.fi/api/getApys')
apy_data = response.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(apy_data['data'].values())
df['keys'] = apy_data['data'].keys()
```

Output:

```
>>> df

   baseApy     crvApy  crvBoost additionalRewards  crvPrice             keys
0     2.44   0.964838       1.0                []      2.82         compound
1     2.00   0.009554       1.0                []      2.82             usdt
2     1.16   0.525497       1.0                []      2.82            iearn
3     1.30   1.165697       1.0                []      2.82             busd
4     0.18   1.574837       1.0                []      2.82           susdv2
5     0.23   0.000000       1.0                []      2.82              pax
6     0.18   0.148985       1.0                []      2.82              ren
7     0.13   0.040684       1.0                []      2.82             sbtc
8     0.01   0.480059       1.0                []      2.82             hbtc
9     0.25   0.570588       1.0                []      2.82            3pool
10    0.67   0.600278       1.0                []      2.82             gusd
11    0.48   3.964042       1.0                []      2.82             husd
12    0.27  20.728590       1.0                []      2.82             usdk
13    0.41   3.508299       1.0                []      2.82             usdn
14    0.13        NaN       1.0                []      2.82          linkusd
15    0.14   2.583800       1.0                []      2.82             musd
16    0.09   0.000000       1.0                []      2.82              rsv
17    0.11   0.322175       1.0                []      2.82             tbtc
18    0.06   1.229910       1.0                []      2.82             dusd
19    0.05   0.003517       1.0                []      2.82             pbtc
20    0.47   0.003374       1.0                []      2.82             bbtc
21    0.11   0.061936       1.0                []      2.82             obtc
22    4.33   3.605098       1.0                []      2.82              ust
23    0.06   1.366844       1.0                []      2.82             eurs
24    0.04   0.439215       1.0                []      2.82             seth
25    2.43   0.289096       1.0                []      2.82             aave
26    2.09   0.291273       1.0                []      2.82            steth
27    1.18   0.035047       1.0                []      2.82            saave
28    3.02   0.324262       1.0                []      2.82          ankreth
29    0.10   2.862594       1.0                []      2.82             usdp
30    0.92   3.238668       1.0                []      2.82               ib
31    0.14   0.223155       1.0                []      2.82             link
32    0.13   0.578532       1.0                []      2.82             tusd
33    0.16   2.683678       1.0                []      2.82             frax
34    0.30   1.850622       1.0                []      2.82             lusd
35    0.59   1.829181       1.0                []      2.82           busdv2
36    1.18   0.018490       1.0                []      2.82             reth
37    0.24   2.378477       1.0                []      2.82            alusd
38    0.35   3.739183       1.0                []      2.82              mim
39    0.15  30.089346       1.0                []      2.82        tricrypto
40    0.66   1.973848       1.0                []      2.82       tricrypto2
41    0.04   0.000000       1.0                []      2.82             eurt
42    0.18   2.032981       1.0                []      2.82          eurtusd
43    0.13   1.608383       1.0                []      2.82          eursusd
44    1.86   0.000000       1.0                []      2.82           crveth
45    0.41   2.397770       1.0                []      2.82              rai
46    2.19   0.000000       1.0                []      2.82           cvxeth
47    0.17   0.000000       1.0                []      2.82          xautusd
48    5.30   0.124506       1.0                []      2.82         spelleth
49    0.73   1.769526       1.0                []      2.82             teth
50     NaN        NaN       NaN               NaN       NaN  generatedTimeMs
```

---

Assuming that you don't want the `generatedTimeMs` info
you can do

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://api.curve.fi/api/getApys')
apy_data = response.json()
apy_data['data'].pop('generatedTimeMs')

df = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(apy_data['data'], orient='index')
      .rename_axis(index='keys')
      .reset_index()
)
```